# Does this look typical for a call to a method that handles Sequelize?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

When I run this with a valid `AccountNo_Lender`, the database updates fine. If I pass null as shown above, I was expecting to see the one-line error `error has occurred` but I get what's shown below in the blockquote. What might be happening here?

**console.js**

```
const contracts = require('./service');

let contractToUpdate = {
    idContract: 102,
    AccountNo_Lender: null
};

(async () => {

    var results2 = await contracts.update(contractToUpdate);
    console.log(results2);
})();
```

**service.js**

```
require('dotenv/config');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

const sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env.DATABASE, process.env.USER, process.env.PASSWORD, {
    host: process.env.HOST,
    dialect: 'mysql',
    operatorsAliases: false,

    pool: {
        max: 5,
        min: 0,
        acquire: 30000,
        idle: 10000
    }

}, {
        define: {
            timestamps: false,
            freezeTableName: true
        }
    });

sequelize
    .authenticate()
    .then(() => {
        console.log('Connection has been established successfully.');
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', err);
    });

/**
 * Model for the contract entity.
 */
const Contract = sequelize.define('Contract', {
    idContract: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    AccountNo_Lender: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    }
});


    
    exports.update = function (contract) {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            Contract.insertOrUpdate(contract)
                .then(c => {
                    resolve(c);
                }).catch(err => {
                    reject('error has occurred.');
                });
        });
    };
```

**Rejected promise**

> C:\code\mypgm>node console.js (node:23304)
> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection
> (rejection id: 1): error has occurred. (node:23304) [DEP0018]
> DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In
> the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the
> Node.js process with a non-zero exit code. Executing (default): SELECT
> 1+1 AS result Connection has been established successfully.

**Update:**
If I put a try/catch around the caller like suggested below I get something better but not sure how `error message` occurred before `connection message`?

```
C:\code\eca-contracts>node console.js
error has occurred.
Executing (default): SELECT 1+1 AS result
Connection has been established successfully.
```

Comment: This looks right to me. You get a `warning` that a rejected promise has not been handled. What were you expecting? Its not an error

Comment: I was expecting to just see `error has occurred`. It says `promise has not been handled`  How do I handle it? It also says `Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated`

Comment: This is because you must not be handling a promise rejection of `new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {`. You need to catch this promise. You can also `resolve` the promise instead of `reject` and handle it where you are calling your `update` function

Answer (score 0):

You should handle error which is rejected in a `Promise`. Use `try` `catch` when calling a Promise method.

```
(async () => {
    try {
        var results2 = await contracts.update(contractToUpdate);
        console.log(results2);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
})();
```

Comment: you can't push the `try catch` in the service?

Comment: No. Since you are calling the promise method inside ‘console.js’, you have to catch error inside it

Comment: I tried that...  `C:\code\eca-contracts>node console.js  
error has occurred.  
Executing (default): SELECT 1+1 AS result  
Connection has been established successfully.` This is better but how did the `error message` occur before the message `Connection has been established successfully`  === if this is hard to read, I updated the OP at the bottom.